# How do I make images appear and disappear without an event or buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have searched Google, until I'm blue in the face. I've tried various codes and have been extremely unsuccessful. I know there has to be a way of having images appear/disappear in a random sequence in the same locations to where 1 image is always on. There are 4 total images. I'm coding in HTML5 and here is an example of the coding:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
   <figure id="suv">
        <img src="./cadillac_escalade.png" alt="SUV" style="float: right" width="210" height="155">         
   </figure>
   <figure id="car">
        <img src="./ICAR.png" alt="Car" style="float: left" width="220" height="135">
   </figure>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
figure
{
display: block;
}
```

and

```
.blink {
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: steps(5, start);
}
@keyframes blink {
    80% {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/r6dje/, CSS code, with some modifications I've fouond on this website. However, I don't need it to blink, just appear/disappear/reappear. As you can tell I'm decently well versed in html, but for some reason this issue is driving me crazy! If anyone can shed some light on this and help me get this code working properly, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed what you mean by the fact that you wish to have the element appear/disappear/reappear. Are you saying you just dont want fading, you just want it to immediately disappear/reappear?

Comment: So you name the animation "blink", but you don't want it to blink, you want it to appear/disappear/reappear? I don't get it.

Comment: would animation-delay would be a hint http://jsfiddle.net/r6dje/436/ (unprefix, add it if needed for your browser.`img:nth-child(even) {
    animation-delay:0.5s;
}`

Comment: And you cannot use Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to alternate the 4 images, only one for a time?

Comment: This only change the images, but not random... Hope it can help: http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8UV/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, That is correct. Apologies for not explaining myself correctly. Yes, I want each image to show initially on the webpage, then I want them to maintain 1 image on while the others are off in a random sequence. I gave an example of the CSS formatting for the figure element. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @tommysshadow, I'm not restricting myself to just CSS or HTML, if I can find a way to get it to work in Javascript I would love it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Oriol, the CSS code example is what I have tried but obviously failed to get it to do what I want it to. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I posted the answer, have a look and please accept it I helped you :)

Comment: @user3649903, Yes, it works like I want it to. I just have to figure out the randomization of it. Thank you for all your hard work and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a little CSS animation example, hope it can help :)

```
@-webkit-keyframes myAnimation {
      0% {background-image: url(img1.jpg);opacity: 0;}
   8.33% {background-image: url(img1.jpg);opacity: 1;}
  16.66% {background-image: url(img1.jpg);opacity: 0;}

     25% {background-image: url(img2.jpg);opacity: 0;}
  33.32% {background-image: url(img2.jpg);opacity: 1;}
  41.65% {background-image: url(img2.jpg);opacity: 0;}

     50% {background-image: url(img3.jpg);opacity: 0;}
  58.31% {background-image: url(img3.jpg);opacity: 1;}
  66.64% {background-image: url(img3.jpg);opacity: 0;}

     75% {background-image: url(img4.jpg);opacity: 0;}
   83.3% {background-image: url(img4.jpg);opacity: 1;}
  91.63% {background-image: url(img4.jpg);opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
.myDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: myAnimation 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: myAnimation 5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: myAnimation 5s linear infinite;
}
```

etc...

```
@-moz-keyframes myAnimation {
    0% { }
   50% { }
  100% { }
}
@-o-keyframes myAnimation {
    0% { }
   50% { }
  100% { }
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Thank you! It definitely works for what I'm looking for. Just need to get the randomization figured out. You have been a really big help. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/begin.html . Scroll down and pic the code you like.

Answer (score 0):

If these images were all in one image as a CSS sprite, then changing the image would be as simple as changing its background position coordinates.  That can be done rather simply in javascript with a .css styling command.  I mention this change in tactics because it is much simpler; there's a lot more documentation on that type of approach.  If you don't get the HTML5 answer you'd like, perhaps a sprite would be the answer.